# lodash findindex push to an array

Tags: lodash

I am using `_.findIndex` which returns me an array, which needs to be pushed to array. How can I do this?

```
   $scope.filtersRequested[_.findIndex( $scope.filtersRequested, {
'codeColumnName': $scope.refData[idx].codeColumnName
                                       } )].filterCondition = strWhere;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to set filterCondition on a specific value. Since you use lodash, you'd better use _.set which is safe (i.e. does not fail if the first arg is undefined) and _.find (to get access to the relevant request). Hence, I'd suggest you do:

```
_.set(
 _.find( $scope.filtersRequested, {'codeColumnName': $scope.refData[idx].codeColumnName} ) ,
 'filterCondition', strWhere
);
```

If an element was found, the _.set will operate on it, otherwise, it will gracefully ignore it.